# How to compile different Patterns with String?

Tags: java, regex

I need to define multi Pattern to compile with String and after running it should give me any thing in the string that has the same format in my Pattern. here is codes :

```
     String line = "This order was places for QT 30.00$ !OK ? ";

  Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
        Pattern.compile("\\d+[.,]\\d+.[$] ", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
        Pattern.compile("\\d:\\d\\d",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE)     
        };      // Create a Pattern object

  // Now create matcher object.
      for (Pattern scriptPattern : patterns){
          Matcher m = scriptPattern.matcher(line);
 System.out.println(m.group());
         }      }
```

Comment: Where are the multiple patterns?

Comment: Multiple Patterns as in you want your string to match with multiple regular expression strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
private static Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
    Pattern.compile("Your pattern ", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
    Pattern.compile("your pattern",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE)     
    };
```

You can use this to go through the patterns and match them

```
 for (Pattern scriptPattern : patterns){
                    Matcher m = scriptPattern.matcher(line)
                     while (m.find()) {
                 String d = m.group();
                 if(d != null) {
                     System.out.print(d);

                 }

            }
    }
```

Comment: i get error with (private static) 
and in the console i get the error Exception :::
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method compile(String) in the type Pattern is not applicable for the arguments (Pattern[])

 at PM.main(PM.java:17)

Comment: Dear  Thilo multi pattern is  this String pattern = "(\\d+[.,]\\d+.[$]).*(\\d:\\d\\d)";

Comment: dear ayushman999 i edited my code like your answer but still give me this error exception::

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at PM.main(PM.java:21)

Answer (score 0):

Using your original question prior to the edit here is a few tweaks to make it work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
    String line = "This order was places for QT 30.00$ !OK ? 2:37 ";

    String pattern = "(\\d+[.,]\\d+.[$])(.*)(\\d:\\d\\d)";
    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) + " with time: " + m.group(3));
    }  
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found value: 30.00$ with time: 2:37
```

Comment: dear Jeremy Unruh but what if i don't make for specific group (place in string) cause i want to any where when get these type of value get them out not in specific place

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You original question was based on the sample you provided so figured that was your issue.  Are you looking just to see if the string is of type pattern in general and not caring about pulling out specific elements?

Comment: dear Jeremy Unruh, I'm looking for any element in the string that has the same pattern format